# Feign RequestInterceptor Can Not get httpRequestAttributs

Tags: feign

I want to intercept the request and add access_token to the header by using the feign RequestInterceptor.
But when I debug in the interceptor, i can't get the attributes. it's null.
How can I get it?

```
@Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
//the attributes is null, what happened
        ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                .getRequestAttributes();
        if(ObjectUtil.isNull(attributes))
        {
            return;
        }
        HttpServletRequest request = Objects.requireNonNull(attributes).getRequest();
        if(ObjectUtil.isNull(request))
        {
            return;
        }
        if(request.getRequestURI().contains(SecurityConstants.MOBILE_TOKEN_URL))
        {
            requestTemplate.header("x-access-type", SecurityConstants.ACCESS_TYPE_PATIENT);
            return;
        }
        if(request.getRequestURI().contains(SecurityConstants.REGISTER_TOKEN_URL))
        {
            requestTemplate.header("x-access-type", SecurityConstants.ACCESS_TYPE_PATIENT);
            return;
        }
        Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
        if (ObjectUtil.isNotNull(headerNames)) {
            while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                String name = headerNames.nextElement();
                if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Authorization")) {
                    String values = request.getHeader(name);
                    requestTemplate.header(name, values);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is using servlet context to get the request, instead of Feign requestTemplate.

This:

```java
ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
     .getRequestAttributes();
// other code to check and manipulate it
```

Should be this:

```java
requestTemplate.url().contains("SOME_URL_FOR_TRIGGER") {
  requestTemplate.header("YOUR_HEADER", "YOUR_VALUE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hystrix request is executed in its own thread pool, so it cannot obtain the thread variable of RequestContextHolder. I hope the following example can help.

```
import com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixRequestContext;
import com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixRequestVariableDefault;

import java.util.Map;

/**
 * In order to pass request context to a FeignClient thread.
 *
 * @author chenwenshun@gmail.com on 2023/5/16
 */
public class ServiceContextHolder {

    private static final HystrixRequestVariableDefault<Map<String, String>> context = new HystrixRequestVariableDefault<>();

    static Map<String, String> getServiceContext() {
        initServiceContext();
        return context.get();
    }

    static void setServiceContext(Map<String, String> contexts) {
        initServiceContext();
        context.set(contexts);
    }

    static void destroy() {
        if (HystrixRequestContext.isCurrentThreadInitialized()) {
            HystrixRequestContext.getContextForCurrentThread().shutdown();
        }
    }

    private static void initServiceContext() {
        if (!HystrixRequestContext.isCurrentThreadInitialized()) {
            HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext();
        }
    }
}


/**
 * First put the request information into the context through the interceptor.
 *
 * @author chenwenshun@gmail.com on 2023/5/16
 */
public class ServiceInterceptor  implements HandlerInterceptor {

    public static final String AUTHHEADER = "authorization";

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        String traceId = Optional.ofNullable(request.getHeader(TRACE_ID)).orElseGet(() -> UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        response.setHeader(TRACE_ID, traceId);
        MDC.put(TRACE_ID, traceId);
        HashMap<String, String> headerMap = Maps.newHashMap();
        headerMap.put(TRACE_ID, traceId);

        String token = request.getHeader(AUTHHEADER);
        String uid = request.getHeader(USER_ID);
    
        headerMap.put(USER_ID, uid);
        headerMap.put(AUTHHEADER, token);

        //put int context
        ServiceContextHolder.setServiceContext(headerMap);

        return true;
    }

}
```